# Only create new columns in loop if needed

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, iteration

I have two data frames (Spike) and (Stim) each with a column of numerics (Spike$Time and Stim$Onset). See reproducible example:

```
Time <- c(0.01598,0.05817,1.08353,1.15216,1.15412,2.13952,2.31006,2.31269,2.4119,3.43013,3.57360,4.90991,5.26342,5.72482,6.52477,6.52776,6.66901,7.39100,7.40102,7.76062,
          7.95643,8.34336,9.24355,9.24680,9.77882,10.85945,11.14801,11.15015,11.37721,12.1896,12.19203,12.33352,12.48023,13.43023,13.51819,13.52033,13.84674,15.01894,15.02114,15.34880)
Spike <- as.data.frame(Time)
Onset<- c(2.370653,3.811336,5.255120, 6.501197,7.848100,9.343938,10.843479,12.164387,13.476807,14.922644,16.419281,17.664224,19.112835,20.660367,21.962732,23.213675)
Stim <- as.data.frame(Onset)
```

For **each** index value in Stim$Onset, I want to find **all** the numbers in Spike$Time that are between 0 and 0.6 larger. Each of the numbers identified, I want in the same row as the Stim$Onset number, but in a new column. The output would look something like this:

```
> Stim
       Onset   Spike1   Spike2   Spike3   Spike4 Spike5 Spike6 Spike7 Spike8 Spike9 Spike10
1   2.370653  2.41190       NA       NA       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
2   3.811336       NA       NA       NA       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
3   5.255120  5.26342  5.72482       NA       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
4   6.501197  6.52477  6.52776  6.66901       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
5   7.848100  7.95643  8.34336       NA       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
6   9.343938  9.77882       NA       NA       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
7  10.843479 10.85945 11.14801 11.15015 11.37721     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
8  12.164387 12.18960 12.19203 12.33352 12.48023     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
9  13.476807 13.51819 13.52033 13.84674       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
10 14.922644 15.01894 15.02114 15.34880       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
11 16.419281       NA       NA       NA       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
12 17.664224       NA       NA       NA       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
13 19.112835       NA       NA       NA       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
14 20.660367       NA       NA       NA       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
15 21.962732       NA       NA       NA       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
16 23.213675       NA       NA       NA       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
```

I have written a loop that does the job:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Stim)){
  if(Spike$Time[Spike$Time >= Stim$Onset[i]] - Stim$Onset[i] <= 0.6){
    Stim$Spike1[i] <- sort(Spike$Time[Spike$Time >= Stim$Onset[i] & Spike$Time - Stim$Onset[i] <= 0.6])[1]
    Stim$Spike2[i] <- sort(Spike$Time[Spike$Time >= Stim$Onset[i] & Spike$Time - Stim$Onset[i] <= 0.6])[2]
    Stim$Spike3[i] <- sort(Spike$Time[Spike$Time >= Stim$Onset[i] & Spike$Time - Stim$Onset[i] <= 0.6])[3]
    Stim$Spike4[i] <- sort(Spike$Time[Spike$Time >= Stim$Onset[i] & Spike$Time - Stim$Onset[i] <= 0.6])[4]
    Stim$Spike5[i] <- sort(Spike$Time[Spike$Time >= Stim$Onset[i] & Spike$Time - Stim$Onset[i] <= 0.6])[5]
    Stim$Spike6[i] <- sort(Spike$Time[Spike$Time >= Stim$Onset[i] & Spike$Time - Stim$Onset[i] <= 0.6])[6]
    Stim$Spike7[i] <- sort(Spike$Time[Spike$Time >= Stim$Onset[i] & Spike$Time - Stim$Onset[i] <= 0.6])[7]
    Stim$Spike8[i] <- sort(Spike$Time[Spike$Time >= Stim$Onset[i] & Spike$Time - Stim$Onset[i] <= 0.6])[8]
    Stim$Spike9[i] <- sort(Spike$Time[Spike$Time >= Stim$Onset[i] & Spike$Time - Stim$Onset[i] <= 0.6])[9]
    Stim$Spike10[i] <- sort(Spike$Time[Spike$Time >= Stim$Onset[i] & Spike$Time - Stim$Onset[i] <= 0.6])[10]
  } else {
    Stim$Spike1[i] <- NA
    Stim$Spike2[i] <- NA
    Stim$Spike3[i] <- NA
    Stim$Spike4[i] <- NA
    Stim$Spike5[i] <- NA
    Stim$Spike6[i] <- NA
    Stim$Spike7[i] <- NA
    Stim$Spike8[i] <- NA
    Stim$Spike9[i] <- NA
    Stim$Spike10[i] <- NA
  }
}
```

My issue is that this is not very flexible. I would like to be able to use this on similar data sets that may have up to 50 values in Spike$Time that are between 0 and 0.6 larger than index values in Stim$Onset. I want create a loop that only creates a new column in Stim if needed. So in my example, only 4 new columns would have been needed, because the highest number of values from Spike$Time that are between 0 and 0.6 larger than an index value from Stim$Time, is 4 (see row 7 and 8). Columns Spike5:Spike10 were not necessary in this case.

I hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does not work with loop instead it's using a join method. But you just get the minimal number of Time-columns - for your example 4.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)

Stim %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(Spike,
                  by = c("Onset" = "Time"),
                  match_fun  = function(x,y) (y - x) > 0  & (y - x) <= .6) %>% 
  group_by(Onset) %>%
  mutate(number = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = number, values_from = Time, names_prefix = "Time")
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 16 x 5
# Groups:   Onset [16]
   Onset Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2.37  2.41 NA    NA     NA  
 2  3.81 NA    NA    NA     NA  
 3  5.26  5.26  5.72 NA     NA  
 4  6.50  6.52  6.53  6.67  NA  
 5  7.85  7.96  8.34 NA     NA  
 6  9.34  9.78 NA    NA     NA  
 7 10.8  10.9  11.1  11.2   11.4
 8 12.2  12.2  12.2  12.3   12.5
 9 13.5  13.5  13.5  13.8   NA  
10 14.9  15.0  15.0  15.3   NA  
11 16.4  NA    NA    NA     NA  
12 17.7  NA    NA    NA     NA  
13 19.1  NA    NA    NA     NA  
14 20.7  NA    NA    NA     NA  
15 22.0  NA    NA    NA     NA  
16 23.2  NA    NA    NA     NA
```